# Update values by regex-matched key from another dict

Tags: json, jq

I have JSON `A`

```json
{
  "a-" : {"v" : 1},
  "b-" : {"v" : 2},
  "c" : {"v" : 3}
}
```

which I want to update with JSON `B`

```json
{
  "a-" : {"v" : 9},
  "b-" : {"v" : 9},
  "d"  : {"v" : 9}
}
```

but only the keys with regex `[a-z]-` in `B` should be updated in `A`:

**Result**

```json
{
  "a-" : {"v" : 9},
  "b-" : {"v" : 9},
  "c" : {"v" : 3}
}
```

How do I do this with `jq`?

Answer (score 2):

Discard keys that don't match `^[a-z]-$` in **B** and add **A** and the resulting object together.

```sh
jq -n '
  input as $A
| input as $B
| $A + ($B | with_entries(select(.key | test("^[a-z]-$"))))
' fileA fileB
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/r95SDcWbTA)</sup>

Comment: Oh, wow. One needs to first see  senseful example to be able to know this.
The doc is sometimes too less practical...